# Story generation from multiple facts/sentences

Tags: nlp, nltk

I apologize for the question being vague/abstract,

but is there a way to generate a story/narrative from multiple seed facts/sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extremely broad question, and it can be interpreted several different ways for several different answers.

### Procedural Generation

One "solution" could be procedural generation. Procedural generation is a technique used by games(not just games, though!) to create infinite worlds, levels, and combinations of experiences. One example of a game that uses procedural generation is Minecraft. Minecraft worlds are massive maps that are generated with a single seed.

Although, this "solution" isn't quite what we're looking for because we're talking about story in this case, not levels.

### Story Generation

Now, generating an actual story from multiple variables can be easy or difficult depending on how much variance you're looking for, and how many variables(or "facts") you want to affect the story.

For example, if you want to change a couple of situations just one way or another depending on whether or not the user decided to kill a monster in order to gain 10 exp, that would be fairly straightforward.

This can be as simple as `if condition is met -> output result`

On the other hand, if you wanted complete worlds, characters, scripts, and assets to be generated from multiple different "seed facts", that can get extremely complicated and abstract. **This type of generation has been studied by countless people smarter than me**, so check out some more professionally written articles on story generation.

### Conclusion

There are different types of generation that can be utilized. If you simply want unending material, take a look at procedural generation. If you want reactions to boolean factors, simply test to see if a condition has been met. If you want a serious amount of material generated from a serious amount of variables, that's going to be a lot harder.

To be frank, **there are many people who know a lot more on this subject than I do**. If you're interested, I recommend checking out some studies and theories from people smarter than myself.

Here are some resources I'd recommend(I've only skimmed them, but I have found this topic to be quite interesting):

http://wikis.sub.uni-hamburg.de/lhn/index.php/Story_Generator_Algorithms

http://kryten.mm.rpi.edu/brutus.preface.pdf

Also, **stackoverflow** is probably not the best place to ask this sort of question as it's a more abstract programming question, but here's some food for thought anyways: How about generating a story based on a computer's MAC address so each story is unique for each computer?